# Chrome goes up when scroll down during animation?

Tags: google-chrome, scroll

When trying to do 3 divs with animation using wow.js don't know why always in chrome while scrolling down and by end of animation of the three divs it goes up again :-(

with Firefox is OK and internet explorer but it doing that hang with chrome only special when doing any animations comes from right side

```
<div class"col-md-12">

 <div class="col-md-3 s1 wow bounceInLeft" >
  <p>my text goes here<p>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4 s2 wow bounceInup" >
  <p>my text goes here<p>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4 s3 wow bounceInright" >
  <p>my text goes here<p>
 </div>

</div>
```

so please help me about that cause iam about to be mad with chrome :-( , and by the way with animation fadeinright its ok and not hanging :-( ??? so what iam doing wrong ?

Comment: **Any Help Here Please**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thanks all problem solved 
By removing padding left and right from container fluid and row inside 
were -15px right 
-15px left
i removed it so animation on scroll become more accurate 
thanks all
```